# Renaming and changing directory structure of millions of files in linux

Tags: linux, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have some 4 million JPEG files that I want to rename and change the directory structure of.

It's not possible to just rename a directory, every filename and directory change is unique and sadly definitely needs to be done one by one.

My only current plan is a PHP script that will read in the old and new name from a text file, and then one by one running `system("mv $src $dest");`, along with any required mkdir commands.

I'm guessing this will take a LONG time - are there better strategies to do this?  Is it going to cause excessive disk thrashing and potentially kill my server?  Would you just set it going and forget it, or break it up into small chunks?  This particular server isn't doing anything else at the moment, so I don't need to worry about QoS of a website running off it or anything like that.

**EDIT:  Here's the PHP script I've quickly knocked up:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

$files = file('old-and-new-names.txt');

$directoriesMade = ['/', '/home/', '/home/originals/'];

foreach($files as $n) {

    $n = trim($n);

    [$old, $new] = explode(' ', trim($n));
    $old = '/home/originals'.trim($old);
    $new = '/home/originals'.trim($new);

    echo "\nOLD: ".$old;
    echo "\nNEW: ".$new;

    $dirs = explode('/', $new);
    array_pop($dirs);  // don't want the last item as that's the filename, not a directory

// go through all of the required levels to ensure the directories are created
// using a php array storing the ones already created in an effort to take some pressure off the disk system?
    $path = '';
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        $path .= $dir . '/';
        if (!in_array($path, $directoriesMade)) {
            echo "\n"."system(\"mkdir $path\")";
            system("mkdir $path");
            $directoriesMade[] = $path;
        }
    }

    echo "\nsystem(\"mv $old $new\")";
    system("mv $old $new");

    echo "\n\n";
}
```

**and a tiny portion of the names**

```
/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/halloween2019990.jpg /0100/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/452d2ebfde0c5cda6f77188d05e21a06.jpg
/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/halloween2019991.jpg /0100/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/a582eeb68ed42fc7169e80d3c02d715e.jpg
/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/halloween2019992.jpg /0100/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/cb36c56995e4d16e20768753485f6174.jpg
/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/halloween2019993.jpg /0101/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/b707951dd72dbcbdae90be76db8dc4be.jpg
/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/halloween2019994.jpg /0101/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/765f9d00e8b18e6a2e41ee14e56fca27.jpg
/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/halloween2019995.jpg /0101/20191103/halloween-charity-ride/dd92d28b72d504329a49db23e51c879b.jpg
```

Comment: There is a command named mmv(1), and also others, that can help you. About disk thrashing, it should not be an issue.

Comment: I've had a look and I don't think mmv helps me as there's no wildcard patterns I can use for this.  The files are all being renamed from their original names to the md5 of their name (I've pre-computed these) and into a new directory structure.  Good to know about the disk thrashing.

Comment: Well, now I understand. I think that with a simple shell script you can do what you want, avoiding the burden of php and system() call. Show us a fragment of the file with old and new names, and someone will try to reply. Also think about to break the long task in smaller steps.. for example, move all file starting with A, then B, then C in separate steps. It can help.

Comment: I've added the script I've just written.  FWIW a test run moved 500 files in 13 seconds so I think it'd take about 30 hours to complete.